# Merge two XML files recursively

Tags: php, xml, merge, simplexml

I want to merge 2 XML files into one recursively. For example :

*1st file :*

```
<root>
    <branch1>
        <node1>Test</node1>
    </branch1>
    <branch2>
        <node>Node from 1st file</node>
    </branch2>
</root>
```

*2nd file :*

```
<root>
    <branch1>
        <node2>Test2</node2>
    </branch1>
    <branch2>
        <node>This node should overwrite the 1st file branch</node>
    </branch2>
    <branch3>
        <node>
            <subnode>Yeah</subnode>
        </node>
    </branch3>
</root>
```

*Merged file :*

```
<root>
    <branch1>
        <node1>Test</node1>
        <node2>Test2</node2>
    </branch1>
    <branch2>
        <node>This node should overwrite the 1st file branch</node>
    </branch2>
    <branch3>
        <node>
            <subnode>Yeah</subnode>
        </node>
    </branch3>
</root>
```

I want the second file to be added to the first file. Of course the merging can be done with any depth of the XML.

I have searched on Google and didn't found a script that worked properly.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Here is a very similar question to what you just asked. There are a couple of solutions mentioned on it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648471/merge-two-xml-files-in-java.

Comment: Yah but it is in Java :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: append one tree to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418019/simplexml-append-one-tree-to-another)

Answer (score 4):

[xml2array](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/) is a function that converts an xml document to an array.  Once the two arrays are created,  you can use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to merge them.  Then you can convert the array back to xml with [`XmlWriter`](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3391) (should already be installed).

Comment: Thanks for your help Tandu but what about if I have attribute in XML ?

Comment: This method will take some tweaking..this is just to get started.  I think that these methods handle attributes too, but maybe not.  You would have to test it out.

Comment: this sounds like a horrible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice solution from comment on [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php), working also with attributes too:

```
function append_simplexml(&$simplexml_to, &$simplexml_from)
{
    foreach ($simplexml_from->children() as $simplexml_child)
    {
        $simplexml_temp = $simplexml_to->addChild($simplexml_child->getName(), (string) $simplexml_child);
        foreach ($simplexml_child->attributes() as $attr_key => $attr_value)
        {
            $simplexml_temp->addAttribute($attr_key, $attr_value);
        }

        append_simplexml($simplexml_temp, $simplexml_child);
    }
}
```

There also is sample of usage.