# Combine two XML PHP

Tags: php, xml, merge, html-table

I'm trying to combine two or more xml files for better use. Let's say I have two XML files and I want to combine their content before extract their data into a table.

```
<table id="rounded-corner">
    <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Download Link</th>
            <th>Language</th>
    </tr>


<?php

        $xml_request_url = 'file.xml';
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_request_url, null, true);



        foreach ( $xml->results->content as $item )
        {

        echo "


<tr><td>" . $item->movie . "</td><td><a href=" . $item->download . ">Download Link</a>    </td><td>" . $item->language . "</td></tr>
";

}

        ?> </table>
```

Can you  give me an example of how to do it? I don't want to make tables for each XML file I have.

```
<find>
<base>
http://www.example.com
</base>
<results items="2" itemsfound="2">
<song>
  <downloadlink>
  http://example.com/dldlink.php?lk=43543
  </downloadlink>
  <format>
  mp3
  </format>
</song>
<song>
  <downloadlink>
  http://example.com/dldlink.php?lk=87798
  </downloadlink>
  <format>
  mp4
  </format>
 </song>
 </results>
 </find>
```

Comment: Check out this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385666/merge-two-xml-files-recursively) / possible duplicate

Comment: they are simple xml, same format but different content

Comment: @showerhead: That question is not yet answered. However I know this question has been asked and answered before, the TS should really use the search for the answer.

Comment: why you guys vote negative the question?

Comment: This is not the same. The other post is about merging xml files, the TS wants to display the data from 2 xml files in the same table. There's a difference.

Comment: @hakre can you show me how to make one table for all files?

Comment: @user1040157: [That's my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10619490/367456).

Comment: @user1040157: I added the HTML around it, so it's probably more clear. It should be enough to demonstrate that it must not change much compared to your original code (I modified it a bit, but you can ignore that, the important part is how to create the iterator you use inside the foreach that outputs the table rows.)

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to AppendIterator::append() must implement interface Iterator, instance of SimpleXMLElement given in /home/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question actually is not asking about how to join two XML files, but more precisely how to create one iterator out of the two. That's possible by using the [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/AppendIterator):

```
<table id="rounded-corner">
    <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Download Link</th>
            <th>Language</th>
    </tr>
<?php

    $content = new AppendIterator();
    $content->append(new IteratorIterator(simplexml_load_file('file1.xml')->results->content));
    $content->append(new IteratorIterator(simplexml_load_file('file2.xml')->results->content));
    foreach($content as $item)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $item->movie ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?= $item->download ?>">Download Link</a></td>
        <td><?= $item->language ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to AppendIterator::append() must implement interface Iterator, instance of SimpleXMLElement given in /home/

Comment: Can you show me how to do it on the code you've posted, please?

Comment: @user1040157: Sure, see the edit. That works. Ensure you select the right elements from the XML, the ones here aren't those in your XML example (verify the tag names).

Comment: how to to query result with xpath?

Comment: @Mehmet you could merge both files first -or- apply the same xpath on both files and create the iterator from the xpath result (use `ArrayIterator` on the `xpath()` return value as it returns arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in an intermediate array. For example:

```
$files = array('test1.xml','test2.xml');
$data = array();
foreach($files as $file)
{
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_request_url, null, true);
 foreach($xml as $node)
   $data[] = $node;
}
```

Then use your $data array to get all the values.