# Foreach two nodelist at once - PHP

Tags: php, xpath, foreach, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Best way to iterate two parallel arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132210/php-best-way-to-iterate-two-parallel-arrays)

I am using PHP DOMDocument to parse some html data frm a football bet-site.

I have one Xpath searching for the home-team and another
searching for the away-team.

When i get the data in the variables `$teamHome` and `$teamAway`
i want to do something like this:

```
foreach($teamHome as team1)&&($teamAway as team2){
    echo $team1->nodeValue . " vs " . $team2->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: If `MultipleIterator` is not what you are looking for, see if an [AppendIterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619315/combine-two-xml-php) will do.

Comment: Check the examples at http://php.net/MultipleIterator and http://php.net/AppendIterator on the pages for `__construct()`

Comment: On a sidenote, you can join two XPath queries by using the UNION operator between them, e.g. `//foo | //bar` which would give you the results in one DOMNodeList

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your answers. The pipe solution doesn't help me because i want in every loop 2 nodeValues. The multipleiterotor solution is intersting. Can u give an example? is it gonna work for nodelist or is only for arrays. I didnh know that exist before 30mins.. Thanks anyway!