# Load XML Sources and show mixed content

Tags: php, xml

What is the way to load more than one XML (different sources) and show a mixed content?

My Code is now loading only one XML now

```
<?php 

            $mobile = simplexml_load_file('mobile.xml');
            $electronics = simplexml_load_file('electronics.xml');

                foreach($mobile->product as $product) 
                { 
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3">'."\n";
                    echo '<h4 class="img-responsive"><a href="'.$product->url.'">'.$product->name.'</a></h4>'."\n";
                    echo '<p><a href="'.$product->url.'"><img src="'.$product->image->large.'" class="img-responsive" /></a></p>'."\n";
                    echo '<p>'.$product->Price.'</p>'."\n";
                    echo '</div><!--end painting_record-->'."\n";

                } 
                foreach($electronics->product as $product) 
                { 
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3">'."\n";
                    echo '<h4 class="img-responsive"><a href="'.$product->url.'">'.$product->name.'</a></h4>'."\n";
                    echo '<p><a href="'.$product->url.'"><img src="'.$product->image->large.'" class="img-responsive" /></a></p>'."\n";
                    echo '<p>'.$product->Price.'</p>'."\n";
                    echo '</div><!--end painting_record-->'."\n";

                }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should provide XML example files for that and also perhaps which output you get (perhaps simplified) and which output you are looking for instead. To mix two `Simplexml` elements for one `foreach` please see as well here: [Combine two XML PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10619315/367456) - It has an answer that shows how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Mix them how?  It looks like your code would show them all in one list with mobile on the top and electronics at the bottom.  I guess you could do something like (paracoding here)...

```
foreach($mobile->product as $product) { array_push($newList,$product); }
foreach($electronics->product as $product) { array_push($newList,$product); }
```

Then do a foreach on $newList, but sorting them however you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Mixing by taking one from the first than from the second. You are right my Code above has one on the top the second on the bottom.

Comment: And you're sure the two lists will always have the same number of products so they can be evenly striped?

Comment: Yes they will have.. The one is just the copy of the second but with other content