# SimpleXML insert Processing Instruction (Stylesheet)

Tags: php, xml, xslt, simplexml

I want to integrate an `XSL` file in an `XML` string gived me by `php` `CURL` command.
I tryed this

```
$output = XML gived me by curl option;
$hotel = simplexml_load_string($output);
$hotel->addAttribute('?xml-stylesheet type=”text/xsl” href=”css/stile.xsl”?');
echo $hotel->asXML();
```

Doing this when I see the XML on browser, I receive the file without the stylesheet.
Where is my error?

Comment: What are `”`? Does it work the same way as `"`?... And what is your error?

Comment: Sorry now I have edited: Doing this when I see the XML on browser, I receive the file without the stylesheet. Where is my error?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm saying... What try replacing those `”` with `"`

Comment: I have tried now, but is the same

Comment: I would not not how to do this with SimpleXML... I'd use [`DOM::CreateProcessingInstruction`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php) (a processing instruction is NOT a regular element), you can always convert if to/from `SimpleXML` whenever you like.

Comment: I tried this now with exemple of php manual:
$xslt = $output->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="css/stile.xsl"');
$output->appendChild($xslt);
echo $output->asXML(); but the page is blank with this

Comment: @antonio esposito: You need to import into DOM first, I added an example as an answer that shows how this can be done (it's not the only way, just one example). Also if you get a blank page, you have missed to enable error reporting to the highest level in development and tracking the error log / display: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456)

Answer (score 3):

A *SimpleXMLElement* does not allow you by default to create and add a *Processing Instruction* (PI) to a node. However the sister library *DOMDocument* allows this. You can marry the two by extending from *SimpleXMLElement* and create a function to provide that feature:

```
class MySimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function addProcessingInstruction($target, $data = NULL) {
        $node   = dom_import_simplexml($this);
        $pi     = $node->ownerDocument->createProcessingInstruction($target, $data);
        $result = $node->appendChild($pi);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This then is easy to use:

```
$output = '<hotel/>';
$hotel  = simplexml_load_string($output, 'MySimpleXMLElement');
$hotel->addProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"');
$hotel->asXML('php://output');
```

Exemplary output (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hotel>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
</hotel>
```

Another way is to insert an XML chunk to a simplexml element: [*"PHP SimpleXML: insert node at certain position"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3361590/367456) or [*"Insert XML into a SimpleXMLElement"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831397/367456).

Comment: beautiful, but it insert the stylesheet at the end of the XML string, can it generate any problems?

Comment: Try, I dunno ;) The alternative is to not append but to [insert before](http://php.net/domnode.insertbefore) if the node [contains children](http://php.net/domnode#domnode.props.childnodes). - Just seeing you actually do not even need to test. Instead of `->appendChild(...);` it is: `->insertBefore($pi, $node->childNodes->item(0));` - Demo: http://eval.in/30382

Comment: perfect, but it don't recognize the xls, if I see with firebug on firefox there is: <!--<?xml-stylesheet type=”text/xsl” href=”css/stile.xsl”?>--> such as commented.

Comment: Well in my example it works, you must have made some error then I suppose. Add your code-example as an example here: http://eval.in

Comment: Please check, it's not complete: *"Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_exec() in /tmp/execpad-9de4c07387f6/source-9de4c07387f6 on line 3"* in http://eval.in/private/6931bf95a20486

Comment: if I insert all the php the error is "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /tmp/execpad-0a00a6a3187b/source-0a00a6a3187b on line 21" I receive the xml with curl: http://eval.in/30396

Comment: Yes, because eval.in does not support curl there. However I can run it on my end. My first tip for you is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225131/367456

Comment: Second tip: Use SimpleXMLElement to build your XML request post-data. http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: As written, I do not get a problem, here is the variant I currently use: https://gist.github.com/hakre/5585567 - It also shows you how you can use an array for parameters and how to use SimpleXML as well to create the XML more easily like you need it for the request :-)

Comment: But using this I have this errors:
Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 2 to be a class name derived from SimpleXMLElement, 'MySimpleXMLElement' given in /tmp/execpad-b690598e4523/source-b690598e4523 on line 53

Fatal error: Call to a member function addProcessingInstruction() on a non-object in /tmp/execpad-b690598e4523/source-b690598e4523 on line 54

Comment: You need to define that class `MySimpleXMLElement`, it is in the answer here (not part of the gist). I mean this is where we have this class, rigth? :)

Comment: I' ve done all of this, but is the same  initial problem: on firefox there is: <!--<?xml-stylesheet type=”text/xsl” href=”css/stile.xsl”?>--> such as commented

Comment: But for the request to the server that you have done on github, if I want to do a GET request I have to change only the method?

Comment: A bit more. You change the method and you have to move the paraemters into the URL (out of the `"content"` setting).

Comment: @antonioesposito: `content` as array key in `$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(` - and you can add the params to the URL with the array params as well so the difference between the POST and GET code is not that much.