# Generate xml file with stylesheet using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a question about how to add a stylesheet to a SimpleXML generated XML file.
This is my code, but I don't know how to add a stylesheet for this.

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Cart/>');

$Order = $xml->addChild('Person');
$Order->addChild('Name', $_GET['name']);
$Order->addChild('Last-name', $_GET['lname']);
$Order->addChild('E-mail', $_GET['email']);
$Order->addChild('Phone', $_GET['phone']);
$Order->addChild('Date', date('Y-m-d'));
$Order->addChild('Adress', isset($_GET['adress'])&&$_GET['adress'] != NULL?$_GET['adress']:'Not set');
$Products = $xml->addChild('Products');
foreach ($cart as $product_id) {
    foreach($productlist as $list){
        if($list['id'] == $product_id){
            $Cart = $Products->addChild('Product');
            $Cart->addChild('ID', $list['id']);
            $Cart->addChild('Brand', $list['brand']);
            $Cart->addChild('Model', $list['model']);
            $Cart->addChild('Price', $list['price']);
        }
    }
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");
$xml->asXML('orders/' .date('Y-m-d(H-i-s)'). '.xml');
```

And this is the line that I want to add to the top of my generated XML file.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="order.xsl" ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [SimpleXML insert Processing Instruction (Stylesheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567055/simplexml-insert-processing-instruction-stylesheet)

Answer (score 1):

You can try just adding it before the root node

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="order.xsl"?><Cart/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write

```
$xml->addProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="order.xsl"');
```

how to add function you can view here

[SimpleXML insert Processing Instruction (Stylesheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567055/simplexml-insert-processing-instruction-stylesheet)

Comment: This gives me a fatal error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::addProcessingInstruction()

Comment: It's a custom method which needs to be defined - see the linked question.